# Unable to display all fields of ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a View display all my fields. Currently, I've set up a ViewModel and have passed it to my View. The ViewModel is as follows:

*NewReportViewModel.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BugTracker.Models;

namespace BugTracker.ViewModels
{
    public class NewReportViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<RequestType> RequestType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Urgency> Urgency { get; set; }
        public Report Report { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The models for RequestType, Urgency, and Report are as follows:

*RequestType.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BugTracker.Models
{
    public class RequestType
    {
        public byte ID { get; set; }
        public string RequestBC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Urgency.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BugTracker.Models
{
    public class Urgency
    {
        public byte ID { get; set; }
        public string UrgencyLevel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Report.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BugTracker.Models
{
    public class Report
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
        public Urgency Urgency { get; set; }
        public String URL { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that if I want to get RequestType, Urgency, and Report all in one view, I would need to pass it as a ViewModel.

Thus, I have done as follows in the *ReportController.cs* file:

```
    public ActionResult Report()
    {
        var requestType = _context.RequestType.ToList();
        var urgency = _context.Urgency.ToList();
        var viewModel = new NewReportViewModel
        {
            RequestType = requestType,
            Urgency = urgency
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

That being said, I can not seem to figure out how to get everything displayed properly! Here is my view for report:

*Report.cshtml*

```
@model BugTracker.ViewModels.NewReportViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Bugs and Changes</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Issue Name</th>
            <th>Request Type</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Bug Description</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Date Submitted</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var report in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(report.Name, "Edit", "Customers", new { id = report.ID }, null)</td>
            <td>@report.RequestType.RequestBC</td>
            <td>@report.Urgency.UrgencyLevel</td>
            <td>@report.Description</td>
            <td>@report.URL</td>
            <td>@report.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString()</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Whenever I try to run this, it complains about `IEnumerable`. From my research, it looks like the `@foreach` line needs for all data to be `IEnumerable`. However, clearly the Report.cs model is *not* `IEnumerable` (and I don't think I can make it that either).

However, my Urgency.cs and RequestType.cs models need to be `IEnumerable`, since I am using them as a drop-down option in a view for creating new forms. This leads me to my question:

How can I view a ViewModel with both `IEnumerable` fields and non-IEnumerable fields and have it show all the fields? What do I need to change?

Comment: you didn't pass "Report" in your viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help! I looked over several resources, and was finally able to get an answer by studying Mosh's Udemy course on MVC. To start with, there was nothing wrong with my NewReportViewModel.cs, Urgency.cs, or RequestType.cs ViewModels and Models. However, there *was* an issue everything after that. First, let's start with Report.cs...

The issue here was that I had a object for RequestType, and also one for Urgency. What I didn't have was an ID - this is important, because both RequestType and Urgency are tables themselves, and would be accessed from the Report table via their foreignkey RequestTypeId and UrgencyID. Therefore, it should have looked like this:

*Report.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BugTracker.Models
{
    public class Report
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }

        public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
        public byte RequestTypeId {get; set;}

        public Urgency Urgency { get; set; }
        public byte UrgencyId {get; set; }

        public String URL { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My next issue was with my controller. There are actually two issues. First, as Mindless mentioned, I wasn't passing in my Report model in. The bigger issue, though, was that I shouldn't even be passing in my ViewModel to begin with! Really, I just need to pass in my Report model, and then use two .Include() statements in the action to get it to work. Again, here is the updated code:

*ReportController.cs*

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    var report = report_context.RequestType.Include(m => m.RequestType).Include(m => m.Urgency).ToList();
    return View(report);
}
```

Lastly, I would need to update my view to simply accept a model (rather than a ViewModel). By doing this, it would then access the content in the table via foreign key. Also, since I would be listing out a series of reports, I would need to make it IEnumerable as well. Here is the updated code:

*Report.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<BugTracker.Models.Report>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Bugs and Changes</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Issue Name</th>
            <th>Request Type</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Bug Description</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Date Submitted</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var report in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(report.Name, "Edit", "Customers", new { id = report.ID }, null)</td>
            <td>@report.RequestType.RequestBC</td>
            <td>@report.Urgency.UrgencyLevel</td>
            <td>@report.Description</td>
            <td>@report.URL</td>
            <td>@report.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString()</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you everyone for your help! I really appreciate all the advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a list of Reports in your view model you need to list a IEnumerable. The point of a view model is to gather all the information you will need in your view, pulling from many models. If you want a IEnumerable of a model just add it as an IEnumerable in your viewmodel.

You could something like this:

NewReportViewModel.cs

```
namespace BugTracker.ViewModels
{
    public class NewReportViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<RequestType> RequestType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Urgency> Urgency { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Report()
    {
        var viewModel = new NewReportViewModel
        {
            RequestType = _context.RequestType.ToList(),
            Urgency = _context.Urgency.ToList(),
            Reports = _context.Reports.ToList() //Add whatever logic 
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Then in your foreach loop you could do this:

```
@foreach (var report in Model.Reports)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(report.Name, "Edit", "Customers", new { id = report.ID }, null)</td>
            <td>@report.RequestType.RequestBC</td>
            <td>@report.Urgency.UrgencyLevel</td>
            <td>@report.Description</td>
            <td>@report.URL</td>
            <td>@report.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString()</td>
        </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you didn't pass "Report" in your viewmodel, so you might want to add that.

Secondly you can do something like

```
@foreach (var requstType in Model.RequestType)
{
    ...
    //list of RequestBCs
    <td>@requestType.RequestBC</td>
    ...
}

@foreach (var urgency in Model.Urgency) 
{
   ...
   //list of Urgencies
   <td>@urgency.UrgencyLevel</td>
   ...
}
```

since they are both IEnumerables, but the Model itself is not an IEnumerable so you can't do

```
//Model isn't IEnumerable, so you can't loop this
@foreach (var report in Model)
{
    ...
    //both of these are IEnumrables
    <td>@report.RequestType.RequestBC</td>
    <td>@report.Urgency.UrgencyLevel</td>
    ...
}
```

Here is my solution:

First, your report should be IEnumerable

```
public class NewReportViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RequestType> RequestType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Urgency> Urgency { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Report> Report { get; set; }
}
```

then, add Report to your ViewModel:

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    var requestType = _context.RequestType.ToList();
    var urgency = _context.Urgency.ToList();
    var report = _context.Report.ToList(); //however you want to get it
    var viewModel = new NewReportViewModel
    {
        RequestType = requestType, //why do you need this, since it's already related to report, you want display a list of request types?
        Urgency = urgency, //and this?
        Report = report //you are missing report here
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach(var report in Model.Report)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(report.Name, "Edit", "Customers", new { id = report.ID }, null)</td>
        //I'm confused here, do you want to display a list of RequstTypes/UrgencyLevels or just one related to report?
        <td>@report.RequestType.RequestBC</td>
        <td>@report.UrgencyLevel</td>

        <td>@report.Description</td>
        <td>@report.URL</td>
        <td>@report.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString()</td>
    </tr>
}
```